# Doubts over degree decimals, radians and euclidean coordinates for gps data?

Tags: gps, spatial

I am a novice here so please pardon me if I am asking very basic questions. But I am really confused with how to handle spatial data. So I have gps coordinates of two points say (13.05, 54.65) and (13.45, 58.67). These are latitudes and longitudes of two locations. So are these are in decimal degrees right? Or are they in radians? And are these in Euclidean coordinates?

TIA!

Comment: Yes, those are traditionally degrees.  These are 2D spherical coordinates, since the Earth is a sphere.  It's easy to convert to 3D Euclidean coordinates relative to the center of the Earth or any other coordinate system you prefer.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for the clarification! It was really helpful.

Comment: Degrees always; sometimes degrees minutes seconds are used, which have to be converted to degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in decimal degrees, the cannot be in radians, which has a range of 0 - 2*Pi. (variants use [-Pi, Pi].
You can check for plausibility by input the coordinates into Google Maps.

Latitude, longitude are coordinates on a ellipsoid, usually the WGS84 ellipsoid. Formulas often aproximate that elliposidal coordinates to a sphere, since the ellipsoid is nearly a sphere.
So they are not cartesian or euclidean coordinates. 
Conversion to ECEF (earth centered , Earth fixed) , is mostly usefull for aeronautical applicatons.
For caluclation related to the earth surface, e.g a trajetory of an vehicle,
other transformations are used.
The simplest is the equi-rectanguilar projection, working in a range of about 10km, until it gets inacurate.
The most advanced projetion (-series) is the UTM Transformation which is used today my nearly all paper maps. It gives you a cartesian x,y, space with unit 1 m. But it is complex.

Answer (score 0):

By the values it looks decimal degree units. Latitudes are bounded between -90 to 90 degrees which is about -1.57 to 1.57 in radians respectively. Longitudes are either between -180 to 180 in decimal degrees or between 0 to 360.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!